# How to show the total number of requests from each object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the list of requests from offices.

Model:

```
public class Request
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public DateTime Created { get; set; }
   public string Office { get; set; } = "";
   public string Status { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Requests(int id)
{
    var requests = _repo.GetAllRequests();   
    return View(requests);
}
```

Repository:

```
public List<Request> GetAllRequests()
{
    return _ctx.Requests.ToList();
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Request>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Office</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var request in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>@request.Created.ToString()</th>
                <th>@request.Status</th>
                <th>@request.Office</th>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need a function that will count the number of requests from each office.
For instance, I have the table:

```
date-status-office:
18feb-opened-101
18feb-opened-102
18feb-closed-103
18feb-opened-101
18feb-opened-101
18feb-closed-103
```

The result should be:

```
101: 3 requests
103: 2 requests
102: 1 request
```

Just in case, this is a graphical explanation:
[image: image of desired output]

How do I show the total requests per office?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0) to group the requests by `Office` and take the count of each group.  In the controller you could do something like this which returns an anonymous object:

```cs
var requests = _repo.GetAllRequests();
var groupedRequests = requests.GroupBy(r => r.Office)
                              .Select(g => new { Office = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

In the view it would be something like:

```cs
@{
    var groupedRequests = Model.GroupBy(r => r.Office)
                               .Select(g => new { Office = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }); 
}
...
// display however you want
@foreach (var request in groupedRequests)
{
    <div>
        @request.Office: @request.Count requests
    </div>
}
```

---

However, consider creating a view model to hold your `Request` data:

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Request> Requests { get; set; }
    public List<RequestSummary> RequestSummaries { get; set; }
}

public class RequestSummary
{
    public string Office { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller you'd create a `RequestSummary` instead of an anonymous object:

```
public IActionResult Requests(int id)
{
    var requests = _repo.GetAllRequests(); 
    var summaries = requests.GroupBy(r => r.Office)
                            .Select(g => new RequestSummary 
                            { 
                                Office = g.Key, 
                                Count = g.Count() 
                            })
                            .ToList();

    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    viewModel.Requests = requests;
    viewModel.RequestSummaries = summaries;

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Update the model reference in view and display data using `Model.Requests` and `Model.RequestSummaries`:

```
@model ViewModel
...
```